# how to use mysql regexp in django1.4

Tags: django, filter, sql-like

Is it possible django 1.4

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE columname regexp 'a|z|f'
```

I tried multiple filter with 'or' operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform any SQL query using Django just by using [custom SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/sql). Your example would be something like:

```
for i in Item.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM table WHERE columname regexp 'a|z|f'")
```

But you need to be careful with these because changing your database engine in future might lead to these queries breaking if the new engine uses a different syntax or doesn't support some of the feature's you're using.

Using the [Django ORM itself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex) you'll need something like:

```
for i in Item.objects.filter(columname__regex=r'a|z|f')
```

Comment: I'd like to give it a try in django itself